# UIButton Doesn't Detect Touches After Custom CALayer Assignment

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibutton, calayer

My UIButton's target action doesn't get called unless the delegate assignment below is commented out, but then I lose my custom drawing.  What am I missing?

```
- (void)createLayerForPaletteAtIndex:(int)paletteIndex onButton:(UIButton *)button
{
    self.colorPaletteLayer            = button.layer;
    self.colorPaletteLayer.delegate   = self; // Must implement drawLayer:inContext
    NSString *stringForIndex          = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",paletteIndex];
    self.colorPaletteLayer.name       = stringForIndex;
    button.clearsContextBeforeDrawing = YES;
    button.layer.opaque               = YES;
    [self.colorPaletteLayer setNeedsDisplay]; // Calls drawLayer:inContext
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're hijacking the button's layer. You should not do that. UIKit does not expect you to do so. You should create a sub-layer and add it to the button's layer.

Comment: I was adding as a sublayer originally but performance is better when the layer is assigned directly.  (This is one of many buttons in a UITableView.)  I guess that's not a viable optimization.